# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: by iterating a map

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple Angular component, that on rendering throw the following error:

```
MyComponent.html:10 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
Previous value: 'ngForOf: [object Map Iterator]'. 
Current value: 'ngForOf: [object Map Iterator]'.
```

The error is thrown twice, even when moved to a bare-minimum Angular project with no other code (just an AppComponent wrapping this component).

I minimized the code to the most minimal form that still reproduces the problem. I replaced the data service with a hardcoded observable.

#### Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private cobs: Map<number, string>;
  private cobSub: Subscription;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // originally data comes from a service...
    this.cobSub = of(new Map<number, string>([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]))
      .subscribe({
        next: cobs => { this.cobs = cobs; },
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.cobSub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Note that `asyncPipe` is more common for use in this sort of scenario - but I cannot use it.

#### Template

```html
<div>
  <table *ngIf="cobs">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Class of Business</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of cobs.keys()">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td>{{cobs.get(key)}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Why is the problem happening?

How it can be fixed?

Comment: Try to fill this.cobSub in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: @FatemeFazli
 
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.cobSub = new Subscription();
  } 
and implementing the `AfterViewInit` interface - doesn't help. Why should it?

Comment: ‍‍‍```ngAfterViewInit() {
    // originally data comes from a service...
    this.cobSub = of(new Map<number, string>([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]))
      .subscribe({
        next: cobs => { this.cobs = cobs; },
      });
  }```

Comment: @FatemeFazli I moved the `onInit` code to `ngAfterViewInit`. It doesn't help + I don't understand why OnInit shouldn't be good-enough for this code.

Answer (score 7):

It's problem with the way you iterating on a Map, you can try:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private cobs = new Map<number, string>();
  private cobSub: Subscription;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cobSub = of(new Map<number, string>([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]))
      .subscribe( cobs => {
        this.cobs = cobs;
      });
  }

  getKeys(map){
    return Array.from(map.keys()); // add it
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.cobSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

in html:

```
<div>
  <table *ngIf="cobs">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Class of Business</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of getKeys(cobs)">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td>{{cobs.get(key)}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pipe-wuxgb3)

and if You are using Angular 6.1+ , you can use default pipe **keyvalue** :

```
<tr *ngFor="let key of cobs | keyvalue">
          <td>{{key.key}}</td>
          <td>{{key.value}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! This strangely enough works, but I really want to figure out WHY? map.keys() is a valid iterable.
The map keys are numbers, so I can't use keyValuePipe.

Comment: It's because binding to a method ...keys() in the template. It will be called every time change detection runs. object.keys() returns a new object every time it is called and Angular recognizes this as an unexpected change, which leads to your error.

Comment: `getKeys(cobs)` generated a new array each time, by calling Array.from. What is the difference?

Comment: map.keys() returns an iterable but getKeys(cobs) returns array of it. if You change to ```getKeys(map){
    console.log(map , map.keys(), Array.from(map.keys()) )
    return Array.from(map.keys());
  }``` you can see map.keys() is an complex Map Iterator object that i think angular can't detect changes in right way.